# Why is the line-to-ground voltage half of what it should be?

Tags: ground, mains, grounding

Our electric power provider delivers 240 V, 60 Hz split-phase power to residential buildings. I've been checking our three-prong receptacles and I normally get the following measurements:

**line-to-line:** 240 V

**line-to-ground:** 120 V

However, there are two receptacles which have a different line-to-ground reading: 60 V instead of the expected 120 V. For both, line-to-line is also 240 V; only the line-to-ground voltage is different.

What possible connection/grounding error could have caused this?

Comment: Most likely a missing ground connection.

Comment: Missing ground connection as in the receptacle's ground prong is not connected to ground at all, or that the ground prong is connected to a length of wire, but that wire run is not properly connected to the grounding bus bar at the main panel? Could this be caused by capacitive/inductive coupling?

Comment: Follow up: when I measured the line-to-ground voltages of the receptacles which are known to have a *disconnected* ground, I get a reading similar to the one I get when one probe is floating (not connected to anything). I don't get a stable 60 V.

Comment: It might also be missing part of the run.  Mutiple outlets are connected to the same run.  A ground resistance meter suitable for house wiring can be used to check continuity.

Comment: The power phase is split! So the two lines are 180 degrees apart in phase. So they are 240 to each other and only 120 volts to ground. Wikipedia has an excellent article on split phase power at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-phase_electric_power

Comment: @PeterCamilleri, yes I actually mentioned that in my question. But instead of measuring 120 V line-to-ground, I'm getting 60 V.

Comment: I'd start by killing breakers to see if they are common or different.  My money is on common.  I'd open up outlets and ohmmeter each terminal to a true connection to ground.  Compare wiring to a good outlet.  I'd power up connections and voltmeter each terminal to ground.  Something is funky (a very technical term) on your ground.  Again, one of those will be something different.  Kill power, disconnect wires and ohmmeter to a true ground.  You know 240V is on sockets, but ground is funky.  Now you have to trouble-shoot it.  No quick answer.  Just don't do anything stupid!

Comment: If I was guessing, I'd say there is a third outlet with something connected to it, which is giving a potential to the Ground terminal.  But skvery has the truth of it (no ground terminal).

Comment: I guess the gist of the matter is that you should not get these measurements. I gather that you are getting 60 to ground from BOTH lines? If so, it would appear that the ground is open and another device on the line is weakly coupling capacitively between the lines and the open ground. This coupling is common in an input network called a Schaffner network: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_filter. Likely a device on the line has a similar filter.